# Questions regarding to proof of Integral test for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Theorem

$f(x)$ is decreasing on $[1,+\infty]$ and $f(n)=a_n$,   $n=1,2,...$

Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx $ are converging at the same time.

Proof in my book.

Right away says it's meaningful to discuss when $a_n$ decreasing.

And says we have that $a_{k+1}\leq\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)dx\leq a_k$  $k=1,2...,n$

Can you help first how we get this inequality?

Then continues summing this terms we get

$a_2+a_3+...+a_{n+1}\leq\int_1^{n+1}f(x)dx\leq a_1+a_2+...+a_n$

On the other way $F(A)=\int_{1}^{A}f(x)dx$ is increasing($f(x)>0$) therefore it will have finite limit.

Can you explain how we from knowing function is increasing can say that limit is finite?

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality comes from
$$ \forall x \in [k,k+1], \quad a_{k+1}\leq f(x) \leq a_k$$
since $f$ is decreasing. You can then take the integral between $k$ and $k+1$ and obtain the desired result by monotonicity of the integration operator (the magic happens because the integral of a constant function over an interval of length one is precisely this constant).

The fact that $A\mapsto F(A)$ is increasing itself does not imply that it has a finite limit, but $F(A)$ it is bounded above by $F(\lceil A\rceil)$ (upper integer part), which by the previous inequality is inferior to the general term of a sequence that does converge. So it also converges by increasingness + bounded by above character (this reasoning is only valid when $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$ converges as $n\to\infty$)

Comment: Thanks really for answer.What is upper integer part - $F(⌈A⌉)$?

Comment: The upper integer part of $x$ is the first integer bigger than $x$, so $\lceil 0.5\rceil = 1$, $\lceil 2.8\rceil = 3$ etc. It comes handy to switch between continuous objects (like the partial integral defined in terms of $A\in\mathbb{R}$) and sequences defined in terms of integers. Your second inequality actually features $F(n+1)$, and for all $x\in [n,n+1]$ you have $F(x)\leq F(\lceil x\rceil) = F(n+1)$ (for $F$ is increasing)